# What does "quacked up" mean in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, word-play

> Being a penguin was not what it was "quacked up" to be, eh? (Sarah & Duck Series 1 Episode 2)

I guess "what it was "quacked up" to be" basically means "what it seemed to be" but I want to know its literal meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**cracked up to be is an idiomatic expression English.**

He was not everything he was cracked up to be. [supposed to be or represented as being or alleged or understood to be, those last two from the Free Dictionary]

Here, **they have substituted the work quack, generally associated with ducks, for cracked.**

The joke means that ducks said certain things about penguins: They were quacked up [by the ducks] to be this or that.

But that is what they were aiming to do, make a joke.